# ValueError: arrange: cannot compute length - when looping through DF to plot multiple heatmaps with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting to create heatmaps for each month of 6 months in my dataset, following the tutorial at: https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/heatmap-for-timeseries-matplotlib.
Each time i run with my own code I get the value error that "arrange: cannot compute length" with the function.
I have recreated a dataset in the same format as my own to use as the example:

```
# create reproducable df with three columns, date, hour and count.
start_date = date(2021, 5, 1) 
end_date = date(2021, 10, 31)

delta = end_date - start_date   # returns timedelta
date = []

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = start_date + timedelta(days=i)
    date.extend([day] * 24)
    
d = {'date':date}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

hours = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
data['hour'] = np.tile(hours, 184)

data['counts'] = np.random.randint(1, 25, data.shape[0])
```

I have altered to tutorial code slightly to ignore the need for year as a variable. As such my code is as follows:

```
MIN_TEMP = data["counts"].min()
MAX_TEMP = data["counts"].max()  
  
def single_plot(data, month, ax):
    data = data[(data["date"].dt.month == month)]

    hour = data["hour"]
    day = data["date"].dt.day
    temp = data["counts"]
    temp = temp.values.reshape(24, len(day.unique()), order="F")
    
    xgrid = np.arange(day.max() + 1) + 1
    ygrid = np.arange(25)
    
    ax.pcolormesh(xgrid, ygrid, temp, cmap="magma", vmin=MIN_TEMP, vmax=MAX_TEMP)
    # Invert the vertical axis
    ax.set_ylim(24, 0)
    # Set tick positions for both axes
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks([i for i in range(24)])
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks([10, 20, 30])
    # Remove ticks by setting their length to 0
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    
    # Remove all spines
    ax.set_frame_on(False)  
  
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 6, figsize=(14, 10), sharey=True)

for j, month in enumerate(range(1, 13)):
    single_plot(data, month, axes[j])

# Adjust margin and space between subplots
# Extra space is on the left to add a label
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.98, top=0.9, hspace=0.08, wspace=0.04)
```

Each time I run i get the error *ValueError: arange: cannot compute length* which points back to
----> 9     xgrid = np.arange(day.max() + 1) + 1

I have tried hard coding in the number of days to format the xaxis but as each month differs this doesnt compute either.

Comment: What is `day.max() + 1`?

Comment: It is taking the max day for the given month and adding 1. October for example should return 32.   Running this outside of the loop, works fine. Wrapping this in np.arrange() also works outside of the loop.  e.g if you run 'day = data["date"].dt.day' followed by np.arrange it returns an array of the days in the month. I understand for plotting purposes the x axis needs to be one day greater than the month days